# Survey Monkey status:3 errmsg:No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)

Tags: surveymonkey

Just started using the Survey Monkey API trying to access their api get_survey_list, have the auth code as well.

I looked into the error for No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0) all it tells about is the python error and how to fix that.

I am trying to access the API using the POSTMAN REST Client extension for chrome as well as directly using the cURL from the command prompt. For both I am getting the same result. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when incorrect JSON is passed through to the endpoint.  Ensure your JSON is well formed - even just try sending a blank dictionary (i.e. '{}') to the endpoint, as that method has no required parameters.  Feel free to update your question with what you're sending if you can't figure out what's going wrong.